# Why is genymotion running (ONLY) android >= 5.0 slowly?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, genymotion

Android 4.4 and older versions are running very smooth. But Android 5.0,5.1 and 6 are very slow on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS system. I have a AMD Athlon 64 X2 Processor and 3071 MB Ram available. My genymotion machine has 2048 MB ram. So why is android 5.0 and up running so slowly? (Boot takes around 7 mins and i have to wait for ca. 5 seconds after the item i clicked responds.)

Comment: Please don't mark as duplicate because not all android versions are slow. Just 5 and up

Comment: I saw some people on youtube running android 5 in genymotion. It was not as fast as on a good mobile phone but it was useable. Mine is too slow to use it.